# Number of clients on different waiting list per year-month

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count

I have a table with different waiting lists where customers can be registered as waiting.
The start date is the date on which the waiting starts. If there is no end date, the client is still waiting.

I want an overview (on all common start and end dates in the Waitinglists table) of the number of waiting clients per waiting list, per month within a year. I would also like to see the difference with the previous month.

The example table is:

```
create table Waitinglists(
    Id int primary key,
    ClientId int,
    Begindate  date,
    Enddate   date NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    List  varchar(255)
);

GO

INSERT INTO Waitinglists ( Id,ClientId, begindate, Enddate, List) Values 
(1,'201000020','2017-2-24','2017-3-6','ListMO'),
(2,'201000035','2017-11-7',NULL,'ListZW'),
(3,'201000066','2017-3-18','2017-11-3','ListWL'),
(4,'201000066','2017-7-24','2017-8-5','ListMO'),
(5,'201000067','2017-7-24','2017-8-5','ListMO'),
(6,'201000067','2017-12-18','2017-12-22','ListMO'),
(7,'201000068','2017-12-18','2017-12-22','ListMO'),
(8,'201000120','2017-9-2','2017-9-30','ListWL'),
(9,'201000120','2017-12-4','2017-12-7','ListMO'),
(10,'201000147','2017-3-16','2017-3-23','ListMO'),
(11,'201000176','2017-5-29','2017-6-1','ListMO'),
(12,'201000234','2017-11-7','2017-12-8','ListWL'),
(13,'201000234','2017-12-9',NULL ,'ListWL'),
(14,'201000020','2017-2-24',NULL,'ListMO');
```

I think of the following output, but good ideas are welcome. :-)

```
Y-M List    Count   Increased
2017-1  ListMO  0   0
2017-1  ListZW  0   0
2017-1  ListWL  0   0
2017-2  ListMO  2   2
2017-2  ListZW  0   0
2017-2  ListWL  0   0
2017-3  ListMO  3   1
2017-3  ListZW  0   0
2017-3  ListWL  1   1
2017-4  ListMO  1   -2
2017-4  ListZW  0   0
2017-4  ListWL  1   0
2017-5  ListMO  2   1
2017-5  ListZW  0   0
2017-5  ListWL  1   0
2017-6  ListMO  2   0
2017-6  ListZW  0   0
2017-6  ListWL  1   0
2017-7  ListMO  3   1
2017-7  ListZW  0   0
2017-7  ListWL  1   0
2017-8  ListMO  3   0
2017-8  ListZW  0   0
2017-8  ListWL  1   0
2017-9  ListMO  1   -2
2017-10 ListMO  1   0
2017-11 ListMO  1   0
2017-12 ListMO  4   3
2017-9  ListWL  2   1
2017-10 ListWL  1   -1
2017-11 ListWL  1   0
2017-12 ListWL  2   1
2017-9  ListZW  0   0
2017-10 ListZW  0   0
2017-11 ListZW  1   1
2017-12 ListZW  1   0
```

Comment: Great example of asking a good question. DDL, Consumable Sample  data (although I'd suggest using a unambiguous date format (`yyyyMMdd`) as that format won't for some) and expected results. Out of interest, what have you tried so far?

Comment: First you need to create all combinations of *year/month and list* you want (to get those `0` result rows). Then you need to expand the data to one *row per month*, usually done using a between-join to a calendar or select #1 (you must decide how partial months are to be treated). Finally you Left Join #1 and #2 and apply `LAG` to get the `increased` column.

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic422001-338-1.aspx was also very helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 -- might use an existing calendar table to get those rows
create table yearmonth( ym int not null primary key);
insert into yearmonth values
(201701),
(201702),
(201703),
(201704),
(201705),
(201706),
(201707),
(201708),
(201709),
(201710),
(201711),
(201712);


with allLists as
 (  -- get all existing lists first
    -- (a table with those rows probably exists)
   select distinct List
   from Waitinglists
 )
, allCombinations as
 ( -- all year/month/list combinations
   select ym, list
   from yearmonth cross join allLists
 )
, WaitingYM as
 ( -- start/end date as YYYYMM
   select -- *
      list, 
      year(begindate)*100+month(begindate) as beginYM,
      coalesce(year(enddate)*100+month(enddate), 999999) as endYM
   from Waitinglists
 )
select a.ym, a.list, 
   count(w.list), -- current month

   -- difference to previous month
   count(w.list) -      
   lag(count(w.list))  -- previous month
   over (partition by a.list
         order by a.ym) 
from allCombinations as a
left join WaitingYM as w
  on a.list = w.list
 and ym between w.beginYM and w.endYM  -- expand to one row per year/month
group by a.list, a.ym
order by a.list, a.ym
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2523e/1)

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot Dnoeth